# How to get dates between two dates using d3-scale time

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, momentjs

I need to get dates between two days, But the problem is by using the d3 scaleTime hour, min and seconds become zero. It automatically rounds the time. Is there any way to override?

I'm using this formated data with antd Slider

What I have tried

```js
function App() {
  const start = moment().hour(8).minute(30);;
  const end = moment().add(10, 'months').hour(8).minute(30);
  const dateTicks2 = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([+start, +end])
    .ticks(10).reduce((initial, current) => {
      return {
        ...initial,
        [current]: moment(current).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      };
    }, {});

  return ( <
    div > {
      JSON.stringify(dateTicks2, null, 2)
    } <
    /div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-scale/0.0.1/scale.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

how do I get the actual Date with an hour and minutes
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question, but in this way you get the date with current hours, minutes and seconds.

I give you two method using moment methods. The first is to extrapolate `hour`, `minute` and `seconds` from the curret date and set they inside the reduce function.

```
const hour = moment().hour();
const minute = moment().minute();
const second = moment().second();

...

[current]: moment(current).hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Else the second methos is to get the second from today midnight and add it to `current` date.

```
const seconds = moment().diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds');

...

[current]: moment(current).add(seconds, 'seconds').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
```

the final snippet:

```js
function App() {
  const start = moment().hour(8).minute(30);;
  const end = moment().add(10, 'months').hour(8).minute(30);

  const hour = moment().hour();
  const minute = moment().minute();
  const second = moment().second();
  
  const seconds = moment().diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds');
  
  console.log(seconds)

  const dateTicks2 = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([+start, +end])
    .ticks(10).reduce((initial, current) => {

      return {
        ...initial,
        // [current]: moment(current).hour(hour).minute(minute).second(second).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        [current]: moment(current).add(seconds, 'seconds').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      };
    }, {});

  return ( <
    div > {
      JSON.stringify(dateTicks2, null, 2)
    } <
    /div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-scale/0.0.1/scale.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My question is any workaround in d3 js not to round the date-time.
In my results, time becomes zero 00:00:00. Did you notice?

Comment: Yep, I saw that, but unfortunately I don't know d3 library. My answered is based only by moments.